# Play Framework [2.2.0-Java] Custom 404 page

Tags: playframework-2.2

Hi Everyone I'm using play 2.2.0 built with scala 2.10.2 (running java 1.7.0_45)
I'm trying to make a custom Not Found Page but I don't have any success.

This is the code:

```
@Override
public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
views.html.myerrors.page404.render()
));
}
```

But I get this error

```
[error] path\app\Global.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
[error]                 return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
[error]                                                   ^
[error]   symbol:   method notFound(Html)
[error]   location: class Global
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

Does somebody know the reason why and the solution?

Thank you in advance.﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notFound` is a static method of the `play.mvc.Results` class.

It is probably not imported in your code. You can try to import it at the beginning of your file :

```
import static play.mvc.Results.notFound;
...
```

or import just the `Results` class if you don't want a static import :

```
import play.mvc.Results;
...
return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(Results.notFound(
    views.html.myerrors.page404.render()));
...
```